# Why is the `a href` tag changing my icon position?

Tags: html

How can I link the user to a page using `a href` from a font-awesome icon when the user clicks onto it. Code is below HTML.

```
<div class="features-icons-icon d-flex">
   <a href='https://www.google.co.uk'><i class="fa fa-desktop  m-auto fa-5x text-danger"></i></a>
</div>
```

Remove the a href and you will see the position [change.](https://jsfiddle.net/hgax2w0b/)

I want the icon to link to google but be in the same vertical line one after the other. For example like the other two icons which have not got the a href tag code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` tag is overriding the styles applied to the `i` tag.
Consider setting `margin` for that particular `a` tag as:

```
.features-icons-icon > a{
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

[Fiddle or it didn't happen!](https://jsfiddle.net/hgax2w0b/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put FA classes to A tag.

```
<a href='https://www.google.co.uk' class="fa fa-desktop  m-auto fa-5x text-danger"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remove a tag and using onclick on i tag

```
 <div class="features-icons-icon d-flex">
     <i class="fa fa-desktop  m-auto fa-5x text-danger" onclick="window.location.href='https://www.google.co.uk'"></i>
 </div>
```